# Why svg <path> hover not getting triggered with JavaFX?

Tags: java, svg, javafx, intellij-plugin

I'm building a PyCharm plugin using Java 11 and the standalone JavaFX module.

The plugin contains `javafx.scene.web.WebView` that loads its content from an HTML file. The HTML contains, beside standard HTML elements, SVG elements, such as `<rect>` and `<path>`.

I'm facing a problem with the JavaFX WebView behavior - when I hover over a `<path>` element, the hover action is never get triggered, and neither do the hover styles. When I run the same code in Chrome, it works correctly. When I run using Java 8 with JavaFX, it works correctly too.

Does JavaFX fully support SVG, and this is just a bug?
Is there any workaround I can try to solve this problem?

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.5'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
javafx {
    version = "11"
}
```

`JAVA Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.25 x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, I execute this on page ready:

```
// Using jQuery scope svg tags to just those within SVG
const $svg = $("svg");
// Attempt to just select the visible layers, ignore non-visible elements and sublayer elements like tspan, this list may need to be corrected
const $layers = $svg.find("a,circle,clipPath,ellipse,image,line,marker,mpath,path,polygon,polyline,rect,symbol,text,textPath");
// Add hover events, because I can't get css :hover {fill:rgba(125,125,125,0.5)} to work
$layers.hover(
  // On hover start
  function()
  {
    // Get the element we are hovering over
    const $layer = $(this);
    // Get current color
    const fill = $layer.css("fill"); // this might not work on elements that don't have fills
    // Store fill as data for uee on hover off
    $layer.data("fill",fill);
    // Create inverse of fill, you'll have to implement your own invert function, or just use one color for all hovers
    const inverse = ag.invert(fill);
    // If doesn't have fill, will have to implement another hover for that scenario
    if(inverse == null) return;
    // Use standard jquery css interface to change fill
    $layer.css("fill",inverse);
  },
  // On hover end
  function(){
    // Undo hover on $layer
    const $layer = $(this);
    // Set css fill to .data("fill")
    $layer.css("fill",$layer.data("fill"));
  }
);
```

Comment: hmm .. are you saying that you see the hover when you open a webpage (containing the snippet you are showing) with javafx webview? If so, you might consider adding a [mcve] for future readers :)